# Lost iPhone notes, Gmail account

Tags: iphone, icloud, gmail, notes.app

I recently migrated from an iPhone 5s to an iPhone 12 Mini on 8/30/21. I have a few Notes accounts, some of which are linked to certain gmail accounts (so within a few minutes of my writing a note on my iphone, that note is visible under a "Notes" label on my gmail account). After making the switch to the 12, everything seemed to be in order (I saw the old notes and the old accounts), however, I didn't actually check that the forwarding of notes was still working. Now, after about three weeks with the new phone, I noticed that I did not have the new, post-upgrade notes in my gmail account. So I went to Notes -> Accounts -> [my gmail] and noticed that it said, "There was a problem accessing your account. Please re-enter the password for [my gmail]." So I did that.

And then I lost all my notes.

That happened about thirty minutes ago.

Since then, it has been syncing notes back from the last note before the migration on 8/30/21. So I take this to mean that, when I re-entered my passcode, it essentially began a sync that overwrote the existing notes on my iPhone, in that Notes account, with those in the Gmail account to which it is linked.

I am wondering if there is any way to recover the notes since 8/30/21. I have no "recently deleted" folder on my iPhone. Wondering if there is any other cache locally, on the iPhone itself. (It appears that this notes account was not backing up to iCloud, just to Gmail.)

This is pretty important to me. Would appreciate any insight. I genuinely cannot believe that they would have written this "re-enter password" sync as an `insert overwrite`.

Comment: Have you tried to go to the google disk site and see if there is data?

Comment: the new notes are in neither my email (which is where they were being forwarded to) nor my google drive. is that what you mean by google disk?

Comment: Right. that's what I meant. And this is very strange. I think probably you turned off automatic synchronization, or did not know that it was turned off, so there is no data in the cloud, unfortunately

Comment: Do you have a local backup of your 5S? How about an iCloud back up? Did you turn on the 5S after this happened? If the 5S is off, and you're certain the notes are still there, you can save your notes by turning off the internet before you turn on the 5S (make sure that phone has absolutely no way of connecting to the net) and then do an iTunes back up. Once you have a back up, you can work your way in the 5S settings to re-sync the notes to iCloud instead of Gmail, for example. You can also access the notes from a backup viewer. Make sure to do an encrypted backup.